# Rails complex joins query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Here is my basic model heirarchy:

```
class Product
  has_many :inventories
end
class Inventory
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :inventory_events
end
class InventoryEvent
  belongs_to :inventory
end
```

InventoryEvent instances store state change + timestamps for those changes, so `inventory.inventory_events.last` shows the current state.

I'm running into problems creating a query on the Product model that will give me all the Inventories whose current state is `received`.

What I have right now is:

```
p = Product.first
p.inventories.joins(:inventory_events).where(inventory_events: {state: 'received'}).all

=> # Here I get back all Inventory that ever had the state 'received' but may 
not currently be 'received'.
```

My SQL knowledge is pretty limited, but seems like some kind of limit to the `inventory_events: {}` option might work, but haven't found a way to do that.

---

Edit: Here is my workaround at the moment just to show my end goal. Hopefully there is a way to model a query like this.

```
class Inventory
  def self.received_items
    includes(:inventory_events).select {|i| i.current_state == 'received'}
  end
  def current_state
    inventory_events.last.state
  end
end

Product.first.inventories.received_items
=> # Here I get the correct array of inventories
```

Comment: I don't think it's ideal... but you could add `has_many :inventory_events, through: :inventories` to the Product model and then try `p.inventory_events.where(state: 'received').last.inventory`. Is that at least the correct understanding of the problem?

Comment: @pdobb You're in the ballpark. This would only return max 1 inventory though. Let me elaborate a bit on the idea: a product might have 5 inventories, and each inventory might have 3 inventory_events, but only the last chronological inventory_event counts as the current state of the inventory. So, for example, p.inventories.received_items should return all inventories with the latest inventory_event.state == 'received'. Maybe it returns 3 inventories here.

Comment: @pdobb I just added an edit section above to show my current work around which should illustrate my goal here more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this bit of SQL and it's been working for me:

```
joins(:inventory_events).where("inventory_events.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM inventory_events GROUP BY inventory_id) AND state = 'received'")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this through the use of scopes and the merge method.  The scopes will allow you to keep the where conditions modular.  The merge method will allow you to select the Inventories that have an InventoryEvent that is received.

```
# call this to get the inventories for the product that have been recieved
product.inventories.received

class InventoryEvent
  def self.received
    where("state = ?", "received")
  end

  def self.most_recent
    order("inventory_events.created_at desc").first
  end
end

class Inventory
  def self.received
    joins(:inventory_events).
    merge(InventoryEvent.received).
    merge(InventoryEvent.most_recent)
  end
end
```

Comment: @streakchaser Wasn't familiar with `merge`, I like the syntax, but still getting all Inventory instances that ever had the state 'received'. When states change I create a new InventoryEvent to leave a history, so an Inventory instance might have 2 or more InventoryEvents and I need to match only the most recent one.

Comment: See edits above.  You can restrict the inventory_event to be the most recent with an additional scope and another merge.

Comment: `.first` returns a record which screws up the query, i tried substituting `.limit(1)` but then i only get 1 record back total.